# how to connect from ubuntu pc to android in a secure way?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, openssh

I connected to my ubuntu using juicessh android app through ssh, however I have concerns about security, what are the steps that you have to take to make sure that it is secure? can you copy the keys to android by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more secure way, I would recommend **Connectbot**, since it is open-source. Connectbot also allows you to import/export private keys.

## How to import private key in connectbot

ConnectBot uses the OpenSSH version of the key. If you're working on Windows, you can use PuTTYgen to create an OpenSSH key.

### Puttygen

In Puttygen, do the following:

1. Load the private key [File] -> [Load Private Key] (*.ppk)
2. Enter passphrase if applicable
3. Goto [Conversions] -> [Export OpenSSH key] and save

Now transfer the key to the Android /sdcard (root) folder.

### In Connectbot, do the following:**

1. [Menu] -> [Manage Pubkeys]
2. [Menu] -> [Import]
3. Choose the OpenSSH key from /sdcard
4. Click the red lock icon to load the key into memory
5. Enter passphrase/password if applicable
6. (Disconnect current session)
7. Connect!

[source](http://blog.oracle48.nl/using-a-putty-private-key-in-android-connectbot/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can copy your key to your android device an use it with juicessh.

Security concerns are the same as with every other SSH client.

Don't allow root login via ssh, use a tool like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) to ban users after to many wrong login attempts.

If you copy your key to your android device make sure to protect it with a passphrase or use screenlock on your device.

Comment: I have to disagree with the statement *"Security concerns are the same as with every other SSH client"* juicessh is closed-source, the security concerns are a lot different than if you would use an open-source ssh client

Comment: how to make juicessh use the key?

Comment: @Galgalesh what open source alternative do you suggest?

Comment: @Fischer you have to add your key to an identity. When creating a new connection click on `identity` and choose new. On the new screen enter the username and select the keyfile.

Comment: @Fischer see my answer